# How to use if-statement to turn a hover effect off

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me to write the code to turn off a function after it has been used once, please?

I basically have a onMouseover function that makes a js alert pop up when you hover over the link. I want it to stop working after the first hover so the link is clickable. Here is the code:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" onmouseover="myFunction()" href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Logout</a>
    </li>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Warning! All shopping cart data will be lost if you logout.");
        }
    </script>

{% else %}

    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'app_001:user_login' %}">Login</a>
    </li>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Jed. First, can you post your code and not just a screenshot of it? Second, if a user hovers over that and then reloads the page, should they see it again? Or they see it once regardless of a reload/revisit.

Comment: If they reload the page is should show again.

Comment: May I suggest that instead of doing this on hover, you show a confirmation popup when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Yes this might be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag in this case and use that in your function. Try this the code below. When you hover over the link, you see the `alert` fire off, but do it again and it won't show. Then reload the page and try it again and you'll get the `alert` to fire off once again.

```js
var flag = false;

function myFunction() {
  if (!flag) {
    alert("Warning! All shopping cart data will be lost if you logout.");
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
    <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" onmouseover="myFunction()" href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Logout</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/QWwBEZR?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you @justDan You are a legend. This looks very similar to what I was trying to do but I couldn't get it right. Not seen !flag before.

Comment: @JEDBOYLE Yep. It's just a quick hand way of saying if that flag is false then do stuff.

Comment: @DBS Hey thanks for that! I edited my comment after I wrote `flag === false` because I wasn't sure if I could back that up. Now I know! Thanks again.